# Problems with local installation of Magento 1.9.3.8. site

Tags: magento-1.9

It's my first time that I find myself working with Magento, after installing the backup on local using Mamp, when I try to connect to the page I see the following message.

> Warning: include_once(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/amsb/includes/src/Mage_Core_functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/amsb/app/Mage.php on line 36
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/amsb/includes/src/Mage_Core_functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/amsb/includes/src:.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.22/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/amsb/app/Mage.php on line 36
>
> Warning: include_once(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/amsb/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/amsb/app/Mage.php on line 37
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/amsb/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/amsb/includes/src:.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.22/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/amsb/app/Mage.php on line 37
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/amsb/app/Mage.php:54 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/amsb/index.php(65): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/amsb/app/Mage.php on line 54

I have already cleared the cache and changed the links in the database `web / secure / base_url` and `web / unsecure / base_url`.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from the error message you are using PHP 7 in your MAMP installation. Since PHP 7 is not officially supported by magento v1.9.x you should switch the PHP version in the MAMP settings to 5.x and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Inchoo PHP7 compatibility extension:

https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

Comment: Can you explain how attempting an install answers the question?

Comment: I happened to have this problem when installing Magento in PHP7. Adding this extension resolved the problem.